# Strings' syntax deformed after opening vb.net solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to modify an already built and running solution. In .vb file, where Query strings are written, becomes deformed in all files wherever Query strings are present. E.g.

```
Dim sql_str As String
Dim dept_check As New common_functions
        sql_str = " SELECT ITEM_RATE FROM HR.SLRS_P_ANNUAL_COST
where WEF_DATE = (select max(WEF_DATE) from HR.SLRS_P_ANNUAL_COST where ITEM_DESC = 'STEAM COST') and ITEM_DESC = 'STEAM COST'"
```

Above code is running fine in production server. But code should be like this after opening its copy-

```
Dim sql_str As String
Dim dept_check As New common_functions
        sql_str = " SELECT ITEM_RATE FROM HR.SLRS_P_ANNUAL_COST where WEF_DATE = (select max(WEF_DATE) from HR.SLRS_P_ANNUAL_COST where ITEM_DESC = 'STEAM COST') and ITEM_DESC = 'STEAM COST'"
```

Please help.

Comment: You wrote "Above code is running fine in production server," but that cannot be the case because the line starting `where WEF_DATE` has a syntax error. Please review your question and edit it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Later I found that the code was written using Visual Studio 2015 and I was opening in Visual Studio 2013. It is working fine in Visual Studio 2015 as Multi-line string literals are implemented in it.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to let us know what happened.